# Web.config to .htaccess cannot work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been trying to convert the web.config below to .htaccess.
web.config is working, but not the one I convert to .htaccess.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="RewriteBase" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="[?\.\/]" />
<action type="None" />
</rule>
<rule name="RewriteTemplate">
<match url="^([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)" />
<action type="Rewrite"
url="/?PAGENAME={R:1}"
appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors />
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Below is what is have convert, and doesn't work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [?\.\/][L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_]+) /?PAGENAME=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I spent 3 hours surfing the website, but cant make it work.
I want it, if the url doesnt have any "." then proceed to next one. get any words after original domain "xxx.xx.com/abc" <-get abc in this case.
I'm completely out of mind now ;( what I have doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ![.]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_]+) /?PAGENAME=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thank you I tried, didnt work ;( i can access to the page from "localhost:8006/?PAGENAME=TestPage" but doesnt work when i used http://localhost:8006/TestPage

Comment: Did work! Thought [?\.\/] does the job, but ![.] worked perfect. You saved my day, thank you ;)